# CKEditor: Is there a way to remove FORM properties option from the context menu

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I want to remove or disable the Form Properties option in the context menu in CKEditor.  I still want the context menu, but I do not want the form properties option.

I can keep the forms property dialog from popping up by removing the code in the plugins/forms/form.js, but this causes a javascript error when they click form properties, and it requires modifying the CKEditor source code (which is obviously bad).

I am even fine with overriding the event on the context menu so I can pop up a message saying this feature is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify a lot of these settings in config.js.

**[Edited]**

Context menu items (aside from the traditional Cut, Copy and Paste operations) are generally defined in a particular plugin that implements the advanced feature.  In your case, the desired menu items would be defined in plugins/forms/plugin.js (the most recent version starts on line 62, YMMV):

```
// If the "menu" plugin is loaded, register the menu items.
if ( editor.addMenuItems )
{
  ...
```

You could edit this file to not add menu items - which you allude to, or you could simply not load the forms plugin in your config.js file, under the "plugins" section.  The most recent version start on line 271, again YMMV:

```
plugins :
  'about,' +
  'a11yhelp,' +
  'basicstyles,' +
  'bidi,' +
  'blockquote,' +
  'button,' +
  ...
  'format,' +
  'forms,'
```

I believe this to be the easiest approach.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was asking.  I was asking how I can remove the Form Properties option from the context menu (Right Click).

Comment: I apologize that I misread your initial question, thanks for the downvote BTW.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, as the FORMS plugin includes checkbox, button etc... and I cannot turn off Form properties without also turning off all the other forms pieces (which I want still).  It looks like I will have to modify the dialog definition for form properties to make it un-editable or something.  But thanks for the answer, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Man, it must be Monday or something.  Re-edit with the appropriate emphasis on FORMS not TABLES.  I need to go home :)

Comment: Amen to that.  Meanwhile, I found this article had a suitable work around for my problem http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Dialog_Customization